# Azure active directory spa user flow with Nest js backend api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a single page application in react js which has the userflow authentication with google and facebook and email login signup in

**azure active directory External identities**

,I am able to run the flow from my frontend app
but now I need to restrict my api access as well in the backend such that

React App ---->Userflow aazure --->get token --->store in frontend

now i want to allow my apis on the basis of that token only
How to proceed with this ,I have found example -https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-react

But it doesn't have userflow or anything in it

Can some1 please point me to the right direction .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to either implement an [Authentication Guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-the-authentication-guard) or setup a [JwtStrategy](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#implementing-passport-jwt) as shown in the docs in your Nest.JS application.

This sets up middleware that fetches the token from the header and validates before executing your API.

In your React Application, you would have to ensure the token is sent along with requests to your API after [acquiring the token](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md).